# Search Icon Inside of lightning input in right Side

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

How to place the  search Icon Inside of lightning input in right side.

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
<label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-1">Input Label</label>
<div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right">
<lightning-icon icon-name="utility:search"   title="Search" />
<input id="text-input-id-1" class="slds-input" type="text" value="" />
</div>
</div>
```

the above code display like below.

[image]

Tried `<lightning-input type="search">` the search Icon is in left side, Expecting to show the icon in right side. Can You Please help me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this, You need to apply this class to lightning-icon: `slds-icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right slds-icon-text-default`

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-1">Input Label</label>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right">
        <lightning-icon size="x-small" class="slds-icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right slds-icon-text-default" icon-name="utility:search"></lightning-icon>
        <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1" placeholder="Placeholder Text" class="slds-input" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/pUGEEi5qx/1/edit)